# Find if reference has 2 diferent Types

Tags: sql

I need this view to show me the dates, that in the same reference (dbo.Restaurante.Pedido_R), there is Tipo = 'C' AND Tipo = 'P'

If there is only 'C' or only 'P' it shouldnt count

```sql
SELECT dbo.Restaurante.Pedido_R, dbo.Prato.Tipo, dbo.Restaurante.Data
FROM     dbo.Restaurante INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Prato ON dbo.Restaurante.Prato_R = dbo.Prato.Referencia
WHERE  (dbo.Prato.Tipo IN ('C', 'P'))
GROUP BY dbo.Restaurante.Pedido_R, dbo.Prato.Tipo, dbo.Restaurante.Data
```

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rLyh.png)

Comment: HAVING COUNT DISTINCT etc

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question